# How can I pass a string as user-defined function parameter in CAPL

Tags: capl

In CAPL, apparently you cannot pass a string as an input parameter for a user-defined function, according to the docs (see *CAPL Introduction » Data Types for Function Parameters*).

I'm working with file handling, both in read and write directions. I'd like to refactor my code to use a function that accepts the filename as input parameter.

Apart from the obvious workarounds, such as using a global variable, using a system/environment variable, I'm interested in the possibility of other alternatives.

How do you do it?

---

**edit**

CAPL does not provide the *string* type, much like C these are "just" arrays of characters.

In the help page I was mentioning, you can pass a single **char** as parameter function, but not a **char[]** array.

What, rightfully, mr. Spiller points out is that this piece of code works:

```
on start
{
    function("a string");
}

void function(char string[])
{
    write ("my string is %s", string);
}
```

and outputs:

> CAPL / .NET   my string is a string

However, that looks like an associative array to me.

For instance, this compiles as well:

```
void function(int number[], char string[])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

But understanding what is going on is suddenly more difficult, as this won't compile:

```
on start
{
    function(13, "a string");
}

void function(int number[], char string[])
{
    write ("my number is %d", number);
    write ("my string is %s", string);
}
```

> Error: types of parameters do not match.

Finally:

```
variables
{
    int associativeArray[ float ];
}

on start
{
    associativeArray[1] = 3;
    function(associativeArray, "a string");
}

void function(int number[float], char string[])
{
    for (float aKey: number)
    {
        write ("my number is %d(%f)", number[aKey], aKey);
    }
}
```

> CAPL / .NET   my number is 3(1.000000)

works as intended, but then again, I'm unsure of what the caveats of using an associative array are in this scenario (I can't find out a way of iterate over the string with the same syntax, for instance), and how do you address them, if you do.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page: why do you think that you cannot pass a string? Why would `void func(char param[])` not work?

Comment: Mostly due to the reference page I was mentioning. I'm not entirely sure about how you are making this work, to be honest. I'm editing my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help page you are mentioning also says further below something like

*and matrices of the aforementioned datatypes* (I can't remember the exact wording and don't have access to a CANoe right now).

`char[]`, `int[]` and so on are not *associative arrays* but *arrays*.
You may think of them as associative array but the key may only be a positive integer.

As you say CAPL and C handle strings in the same way, i.e. as arrays of characters.
Therefore, coming back to your original question using a definition like

```
void func(char param[])
```

is the way to go when you want to pass a string (which is just an array of characters) to a function.

---

This:

```
on start
{
    function(13, "a string");
}

void function(int number[], char string[])
{
    write ("my number is %d", number);
    write ("my string is %s", string);
}
```

does not compile, because `13` is not an array of integers, but just a single integer. The compiler therefore says the the *types do not match*.

This will work:

```
on start
{
  int i[1];
  i[0] = 13;
  function(i, "a string");
}
```

The same way the following code will also NOT compile:

```
void function(char string[])
{
   ...
}

on start
{
  function('a');
}
```

`'a'` (note the single quotes) is just a single character and no array of characters and therefore the signature does not match.

---

You can get the individual characters of a string by simply using the `[]` operator (also same as in C).

```
char s[] = "abcde"; char c = s[2];
```

will store 'c' into `s`

Hope that explains it. Feel free to ask for further clarification.
(I did type all this from top of my head, so please excuse any minor syntax errors)